# PHP: eval don't have value

Tags: laravel, controller, eval, laravel-5.5

I stored a `Controller@Action` in the database, but when I try to run it it don't has value.

I know that eval is very dangerous. If there is an alternative what I can use in this situation I'm open for it.

My code where I wan't to run it:

```
//$action = "ExchangeController::module_getAllValutaByBank";
//$params = "K&H";
$test =  eval('\App\Http\Controllers\ModuleControllers' . "\\" . $action . "('" . $params . "');");
Debugbar::info($test);
```

The code what I want to eval:

> It's an API request to the local ForexChange site. @param bank's name
>   @return stuctured string

```
public static function module_getAllValutaByBank($bankName){
    $return = '';
    $data['bankName'] = $bankName;
    $response = self::getRequest($data);

    if(is_array($response)){
        $return .= $response[0]['bank'] . "\n";
        foreach($response as $key => $item){
            $return .= $item['valuta'] . " - " . round($item['buy'], 2) . " - " . round($item['sell'], 2) . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        $return = $response;
    }

    Debugbar::info($return);

    return $return;
}
```

Output of `Debugbar::info($return);`

> K&H Bank GBP - 338.51 - 363.07 AUD - 189.9 - 207.8 DKK - 39.75 - 43.93
>   JPY - 2.26 - 2.48 CAD - 188.73 - 206.51 NOK - 30.92 - 34.18 CHF -
>   256.89 - 275.53 SEK - 29.18 - 32.26 USD - 246.14 - 260.32 CZK - 11.51 - 12.97 PLN - 69.87 - 78.79 EUR - 302.92 - 320.38 HRK - 39.39 - 44.41

Output of `Debugbar::info($test);`

> null

Where it went wrong?

**EDIT:**

Found the solution:

`$test = call_user_func('\App\Http\Controllers\ModuleControllers' . "\\" . $action, $params));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

`$test = call_user_func('\App\Http\Controllers\ModuleControllers' . "\\" . $action, $params));`